# Cannot take screenshot with 0 width

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to take a screenshot of an element inside a Bootstrap's modal. After some struggling, I finally came up with this code:

```
driver.get('https://enlinea.sunedu.gob.pe/')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[contains(@class, "img_publica")]').click()

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'modalConstancia')))
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[contains(@id, "modalConstancia")]').click()
active_element = driver.switch_to.active_element
active_element.find_elements_by_id('doc')[0].send_keys(graduate.id)

# Can't take this screenshot
active_element.find_elements_by_id('captchaImg')[0].screenshot_as_png('test.png')
```

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cesar/Development/manar/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rq/worker.py", line 812, in perform_job
    rv = job.perform()
  File "/home/cesar/Development/manar/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rq/job.py", line 588, in perform
    self._result = self._execute()
  File "/home/cesar/Development/manar/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rq/job.py", line 594, in _execute
    return self.func(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "./jobs/sunedu.py", line 82, in scrap_document_number
    record = scrap_and_recognize(driver, graduate)
  File "./jobs/sunedu.py", line 33, in scrap_and_recognize
    active_element.find_elements_by_id('captchaImg')[0].screenshot_as_png('test.png')
  File "/home/cesar/Development/manar/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 567, in screenshot_as_png
    return base64.b64decode(self.screenshot_as_base64.encode('ascii'))
  File "/home/cesar/Development/manar/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 557, in screenshot_as_base64
    return self._execute(Command.ELEMENT_SCREENSHOT)['value']
  File "/home/cesar/Development/manar/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "/home/cesar/Development/manar/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/cesar/Development/manar/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: unhandled inspector error: {"code":-32000,"message":"Cannot take screenshot with 0 width."}
  (Session info: chrome=75.0.3770.100)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Linux 4.4.0-154-generic x86_64)
```

After some debugging, I realize that the element has no width or height:

```
(Pdb) active_element.find_elements_by_id('captchaImg')[0].rect
{'height': 0, 'width': 0, 'x': 0, 'y': 0}
(Pdb) active_element.find_elements_by_id('captchaImg')[0].size
{'height': 0, 'width': 0}
```

I think that's the cause of the failure. Is there a way to get around this?

---

These are the steps:

1. Click the link:

[image]

2. Wait for the modal and fill the first input:

[image]

3. Try to take the screenshot of the captcha image:

[image]

If I inspect the element (the `span` that is holding the CAPTCHA image) in the browser I can see that it is actually 100x50:

[image]

Comment: You're probably not going to beat captcha. You cannot expect that what you see when you inspect elements via your browser to be what your script sees, even when it hits the same page. Captcha is smart, it will know you're trying to scrape the page, and it won't work. Try taking a screenshot of the whole page instead of just that element.

Comment: webdriver `Firefox` gives correct size but function `screenshot()` saves always full page.

Comment: @c0lon captcha is not a sentient being, it's just another element on the page, and can be interacted with and overcome using selenium just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I've figured out why you keep getting `Cannot take screenshot with 0 width.` errors. The reason is that there are multiple captchas on the page, and using a non-specific selector gives you a hidden captcha image (possibly under another modal window). So increasing the specificity should give you the right image.

Here's the code:

```py
from contextlib import contextmanager
from logging import getLogger

from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome, ChromeOptions
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

logger = getLogger(__name__)


@contextmanager
def get_chrome() -> Chrome:
    opts = ChromeOptions()
    # opts.headless = True
    logger.debug('Running Chrome')
    driver = Chrome(options=opts)
    driver.set_window_size(1000, 600)
    logger.debug('Chrome started')
    yield driver
    driver.close()


def wait_selector_present(driver: Chrome, selector: str, timeout: int = 5):
    cond = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, selector))
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(cond)
    except TimeoutException as e:
        raise ValueError(f'Cannot find {selector} after {timeout}s') from e


def wait_selector_visible(driver: Chrome, selector: str, timeout: int = 5):
    cond = EC.visibility_of_any_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, selector))
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(cond)
    except TimeoutException as e:
        raise ValueError(f'Cannot find any visible {selector} after {timeout}s') from e


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with get_chrome() as c:
        captcha_sel = '#consultaForm #captchaImg img'
        modal_sel = '[data-target="#modalConstancia"]'

        url = 'https://enlinea.sunedu.gob.pe/'
        c.get(url)

        wait_selector_present(c, modal_sel)
        modal = c.find_element_by_css_selector(modal_sel)
        modal.click()

        wait_selector_visible(c, captcha_sel)
        captcha_img = c.find_element_by_css_selector(captcha_sel)
        captcha_img.screenshot('captcha.png')
```

result:

[image]

Comment: Hi. That makes a lot of sense. I'm gonna try this really soon and get back to you. Thanks!!

Comment: Dude, you're awesome. I change the code a little bit but, indeed, the problem was that I needed to be more specific in the selector.